# MySQL Count function not working right

Tags: php, mysql, count

```
$req_user = trim($_GET['user']);
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$get_data = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE uname = '$req_user'";
$result = mysql_query($get_data) OR die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$email = $rows['email'];
$gravatar = md5(strtolower(trim("$email")));
$user_likes = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE username = '$email'");
```

I'm trying to count all of the rows in the database `likes` with the email of the current user in their `username` field.
(It's a loop to get info from links like `userinfo.php?user=xxx`.)
When I echo `$user_likes` there is no output.

What is wrong with the code?
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-count-function.htm

Comment: Has this line `$gravatar = md5(strtolower(trim("$email")));
` anything to do with the question?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with the question, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `$gravatar = md5(strtolower(trim("$email")));` is not related to the question here and not needed, you could also use one query to the database, to get the count:

```
$req_user = trim($_GET['user']);
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("cannot select DB");
$get_count_query = 
    "SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM likes 
     WHERE username = 
           ( SELECT email
             FROM users 
             WHERE uname = '$req_user'
           )
    ";
$result = mysql_query($get_count_query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$user_likes = $row[0];
```

Comment: Thanks but the output is literally "Array". using `<?php echo $user_likes; ?>`

Comment: Counting means that you want a number though, or am I missing something?

Comment: That's right, I need a number. But instead, the output is "Array" and not a number. `# of Likes Posted: Array`

Comment: Nevermind! After taking a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php - I changed it to `echo $user_likes[0];`. It's working fine now - thank you! :)

Comment: Yes, you found it. It's an array with one row only and not a number (because of the `COUNT(*)`.)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't fetch it...

Do it like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE username = '$email'");

$user_likes = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

Comment: Same as @ypercube 's solution, the output is "Array" and not a number.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to properly compare the emails (case insensitive) :

```
"... WHERE UPPER(username) = '" . strtoupper($email) . "'"
```

Then $user_likes is a resource variable, it won't give you the count directly.

You need to fetch it first :

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($user_likes);
echo 'Count: ' . $row[0];
```

Comment: MySQL is case insensitive when using `LIKE` or `=` with `CHAR` fields.

Answer (score 1):

You should do that :

```
$req_user = trim($_GET['user']);
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("cannot select DB");
$get_data = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE uname = '$req_user'";
$result = mysql_query($get_data) or die(mysql_error());
if ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $email = $rows['email'];
    $gravatar = md5(strtolower(trim("$email")));
    $get_data = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE username = '$email'";
    $user_likes = mysql_query($get_data) or die(mysql_error());
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_row($user_likes)) {
       $nbr = 1*$row[0]; 
    } else {
       // it could never happen ;-)
       $nbr = 0;
    }
} else {
    // no match with this user!
    $nbr = 0;
}
echo "This user likes $nbr times !";
```